# How to solve following sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider a table EMPLOYEE with columns EMP_ID and SALARY with unknown number of records. Write a query to extract top 25% of the records based on salary?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking us to write your query is not acceptable here; show what you tried, and where did it fail.

Answer (score 0):

25% may mean few things, but the following query should work for the simplest definition.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM Cookie ORDER BY cookies DESC )
 WHERE ROWNUM < ((SELECT count(*) FROM Cookie) * 1 / 4) ;
```

---

For

```
create table Cookie (name varchar2(10), cookies number(3));
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name1', 1);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name2', 2);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name3', 3);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name4', 4);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name5', 5);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name6', 6);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name7', 7);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name8', 8);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name9', 9);
insert into Cookie values ( 'Name10', 10);
```

the query returns

```
NAME    COOKIES
Name10  10
Name9   9
```

---

For the record, in SQL Server you can

```
SELECT TOP (25) PERCENT *
FROM Cookie
ORDER BY cookies DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**percent_rank()**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/percent_rank-analytic-function) analytic function as `percent_rank() over (order by salary)` which returns a value between 0 and 1 :

```
SELECT salary, emp_id
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT e.*,
          percent_rank() over (order by e.salary) as prcnt_rank_for_sal 
     FROM employee e)
  WHERE  prcnt_rank_for_sal >= 0.25;
```